# proxy for mac and windows

Tags: proxy, local

I have a requirement that I need to restrict my kids from browsing some sites . I want to be the adminbstrator for my machine, but other users have limited access to internet. Is there any software / proxy for this ? i want solution for both windows / linux and mac

Comment: Thats good, but assuming kids are doing some research, and they need to google and find some info. so is not there anything that restricts websites only on content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My brother managed his daughters' access on Macs like this:

- Restrict Safari from going to sites not in the Bookmarks
- Only an administrator can create bookmarks
- His user is an administrator; theirs aren't.

Kids can be pretty smart, though, and once they're sufficiently motivated to figure out how to get around your access controls it's not worth continuing the arms race.